# How to use select columns in phalcon Model with relationship

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-orm

I have model named `User` and `UserPhoto`, which is related in one user to many user photo

```
$this->hasMany("id", "UserPhoto", "user_id");
$this->belongsTo("user_id", "User", "id");
```

If I try

```
$userData = User::find();

foreach ($userData as $user) {
    $userPhotoAry = $user->UserPhoto;
}
```

I am getting relational resultset, but i need only selected column from table.

So I tried this,

```
$userData = User::find(array("columns"=>"id,username"));

foreach ($userData as $user) {
    $userPhotoAry = $user->UserPhoto;
}
```

I am getting `$UserPhoto` is undefined.

Is there any way to mention column in find query along with relationship?

Comment: As @nikolay said, it isn't possible to get the related records if you specify columns in your query. Because you'll be returned a `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row` instead of a model instance. Might I add that specifying columns is actually _slower_ than just querying the whole record

Answer (score 0):

With the default behavior you can not. Here is why:

```
// Specifying columns
$userData = User::find(array("columns"=>"id,username"));
var_dump(get_class($userData[0])); // "Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row"

// Selecting whole objects
$userData = User::find();
var_dump(get_class($userData[0])); // "Users"
```

As you can see above specifying columns does not return Model instances, but Row instances, which do not have the methods/relations as you already saw for yourself.

There is a way to achieve it, but involves some additional efforts and I'm not sure that it is worth it. You can read more in **[this forum topic](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/15787/findfirst-conditions-with-trim-function)** and follow the links provided.

Comment: I can understand what you have explained, but i need something which can handle both Users object and column selection from table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is impossible.
Relationship has all columns. Why not ?

or like this:

```
$userData = User::query()
->columns(["User.id", "User.username"])
->innerJoin("UserPhoto")
->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could unset the columns you don't want to use inside the foreach